# How to avoid database deadlocks

Tags: java, concurrency, db2, deadlock

I have a clustered application that is suffering from database deadlocks.

It is a j2ee application using JPA and hibernate.  The database is DB2 8.1 on Z/OS is set to page locking (this is a requirement for the company).

The problem is that the primary key are generated as a sequence, and will often deadlock while trying to insert records if the system has any significant load.

Are there any "best practices" to reducing the probability of a deadlock?

Comment: Follow Up: After implementing the random number suggestion, deadlocks were drastically decreased.  Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Are there any "best practices" to reducing the probability of a deadlock?"

Deadlock means 2 (or more) processes, 2 (or more) resources and two distinct orders for access.

Process 1 has to get A and B.

Process 2 has to get B and be waiting for A.

If every process would get A first, the incidence of deadlock is reduced.

Since you're deadlocking on an entire page, it's hard to assure that everyone gets the same page to start their transaction.

You can try to reduce conflicts by assuring that rows are widely scrambled among the pages.

You can try to reduce conflicts by introducing a "You Must Get This First" row which will effectively single-thread applications.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the rows will be distributed?  I'm not sure how the database determines what page to stick the row in (I'm assuming it is based on the key).  Would adding another field to the key that is a random number (or UUID) help to distribute the rows?

Comment: @Jesse: UUID's are probably random enough.  You have random number generators that are pretty random.  You can also index by some attribute that's good a distribution different from the one causing the collision.  ZIP code, for example.